# How to show sort Product on category section by its Postion in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list, category-products

I have a magento site in which many products are associated with one category.
they are being shown in order in which they were created under category prodcuts tab in manage category section in magento admin. as shown in below image-

[image]

here as you can see in image products are listed with their positions. but I want to listed them according to Position in Ascending order like 1,2,3,4,5,6..

How can I do this.? Do I need to create seperate plugin for this.? if yes then what will be  the first point to start.?

Comment: you should be able to order according to position

Answer (score 1):

Just click the header "Position" with your mouse and the table will get sorted in the order of Position.

If you change the values, you can only sort on the saved values. So you need to save first before the order is based on your new values.